# git で新旧ソースの差分を見たいのですが、内容が同じなのに全ファイルが差分表示される

Tags: git

管理者不在で放置状態のウェブサーバがあり、しかし現在ちゃんと動いているウェブサーバなのですが、その中身（新ソース）とローカルに保存していた過去のソース（旧ソース）との差分を git を使って見たいと思い、

1. まずローカルの旧ソースに最初のコミットをかけ
2. 次にウェブサーバの中身（新ソース）を旧ソースへ上書きダウンロード
3. 2回めのコミットをかけて差分を見る。

という方法を試みたのですが、中身は全く同じ内容なのに差分表示されてしまい、そのため、全ファイルが「同じ内容ではない」と判定されます。
確かにタイムスタンプは全部違うのですが、中身の差分を見たいときに大変な手間となっています。なにかいい方法がないでしょうか？

当方、コマンド系は苦手なので、tortoise Git を使っています。

Comment: 新ソースと旧ソースで文字コードや改行コードが違っている、ということはないでしょうか？

Comment: 差分表示ではWinMergeが立ち上がるのですが、英文のみのソースでも、文字コードはどちらも「シフトJIS」、改行コードが違うときは行末が色分けされたと思うのですがそれもない状態です。

Comment: 似たパターンでありがちなのが半角スペースとタブの違いがある、という場合ですが、これはいかがでしょうか。WinMergeでは、空白がどのようなものか表示する機能がありますが、これで可視化してみるとどうでしょう。

Comment: あぁ、マージツールをデフォルトに戻したら、改行コードが違っていたようです。すみません。WinMergeでは改行コードの違いを無視してました・・・

Comment: @vow 本質問が解決済みであることが他のユーザにも分かりやすくするため、ご自身で回答を記入し承認して頂けると助かります。

Comment: 無回答の質疑として放置するのはもったいないと思いましたので、コミュニティWikiの形で回答を追加しました。

Answer (score 3):

新ソースと旧ソースで改行コードが異なることが原因だと思われます。
差分比較ツールで改行コードを無視しないように設定してみてください。
同様のパターンとして、タブコードと半角空白が入れ替わっているなどというケースも考えられます。

環境ごとのエディタの挙動を統一する[EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/)という仕組みの導入も検討されると良いでしょう。有名どころのエディタやIDEは対応していることが多いです。